# Is Component inside render function called child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-component

I have a little confused about children component. As I know children component is the component nested inside other component, for example

```
<Parent>
   <Child />
</Parent>
```

But what is the component inside the render function of Parent component. What is it called? For example of Parent component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ComponentX>
        {this.props.children}
      </ComponentX>
    )
  }
}
```

Is ComponentX called a children of Parent Component?

I appreciate any explanation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is ComponentX called a children of Parent Component?

NO.

`ComponentX` is called an **Enclosing component** of `Parent`'s children.

Similar to how [`React.Fragments`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) are used, without an enclosing element, there will be a warning:

> Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Comment: Thanks for reply, so what happen if Parent component render function only return ComponentX (return <ComponentX />). Is it still called enclosing component of parent?

Comment: That's a bit unusual since React is based on [Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) pattern. Typically this is an ideal case for [Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

Comment: So Parent component is like a HOC of componentX right

Comment: If `Parent` component is an enhancement of `ComponentX`, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ComponentX>
        {this.props.children}
      </ComponentX>
    )
  }
}
```

`this.props.children` here is of `Parent`, and when you pass them into children of `ComponentX`. In `ComponentX` you will got this children.
Example:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ComponentX>
        {this.props.children} // Here is children of Parent
      </ComponentX>
    )
  }
}
```

In `ComponentX`:

```
class ComponentX extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children} // Here is children of ComponentX that you passed
        // in above
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

> In this case, you get children of `Parent` to use for childrent of
>   `ComponentX`

Comment: Thanks for replies. But I wonder is that what is the relationship between ComponentX and Parent?